# Adding an action listener to a jbutton in another class

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm trying to model my small project off the MVC design pattern. As such I am trying to assign the ActionListener for my JButton(submit) (in the UI class) to the evaluate method in the model class, I'm doing all this in a third class (controller) code is below.

```
public class ExpressionController implements ActionListener {

ExpressionModel model;
ExpressionUI view;

public ExpressionController(ExpressionModel m, ExpressionUI v) {
    model = m;
    view = v; 

            //ERROR: The method is undefined for the type Expression Controller
    actionListenerComponenets(this);
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        double result;
        result = model.evaluate(Double.parseDouble(view.input.getText()));
        view.result.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void actionListenerComponenents(ActionListener ae) {
    view.submit.addActionListener(ae); 
}
```

My problem is in assigning the action listener outside of the UI class (see comments in code)... is there a better way to do this? I know its only a simple example but I want to be comfortable with MVC Design.

Comment: Not sure what your question is...?

Comment: Ah, hidden as a comment in your code.

Comment: Consider using [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Comment: The problem was in the view.... it didnt have an addActionListener method.. and it should have been view.addActionListenerComponents()